# ¿Las funciones y disparadores se interrumpen de raíz si se cae la BD a la mitad de la ejecución?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, transacciones

Tomemos el siguiente ejemplo:

Mi programa realiza un insert en una tabla de la base de datos (llamémosle `tabla1`) y, al momento de hacerlo, un *trigger* en el PostgreSQL realiza una inserción esos datos en otras dos tablas (llamémosle `tabla2` y `tabla3`).

Ahora, desde el momento que yo hago el insert en la `tabla1`, hasta que se ejecuta el *trigger* y se hacen las inserciones de los datos automáticamente en las `tabla2` y `tabla3`, puede suceder que, inesperadamente, se me caiga la conexión a la base de datos.

Entonces mi duda es si ya viene predeterminado o no que el *PostgreSQL*

- Corte toda esa secuencia de acciones desde el principio (es decir, que vuelva todo para atrás y no haga ni el primer `insert` a la `tabla1`),
- Que se corte antes del trigger (que sólo realize la inserción a la `tabla1`) o
- Que corte las acciones a partir del momento en que se quedó la conexión (por ejemplo si se cae cuando va a empezar el insert en la `tabla3`, las inserciones en la `tabla1` y `tabla2` quedan registradas).

Mi pregunta es esa porque me estoy adentrando en el terreno de las transacciones y los rollback, y no sabría si tendría que usarlos en el caso que haya triggers y funciones en general.

Espero haber sido lo bastante claro, agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiera responder a esto.

Comment: Hola, Skywalker. Las preguntas de tipo este tipo se podrían catalogar de "hazme una tarea" por lo que no son bien recibidas por la comunidad y terminan con votos negativos y cerradas. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir lo que has intentado y si algo te da error o donde no terminas de entender cómo hacerlo? Te invito a leer el enlace de cómo preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Saludos.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Hice una edición en tu publicación, no solo por ortografía, sino porque resulta muy cansado leer todo si está en un solo párrafo, de corrido y sin la puntuación necesaria.

Comment: Que tal Adrian. No era esa mi intención, en realidad armé un ejemplo que nada tiene que ver con el programa que estoy haciendo, pero es porque quiero saber si el postgresql trae por defecto la opción de rollback si es ese el término adecuado, es decir el de realizar TODO o NADA en el caso de que se corte la conexión a la mitad de la función. Eso es en resumen mi duda, pero me extendí con un ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias jachguate por la bienvenida y colaborar con la edición de mi respuesta, así lo haré.

Comment: Los triggers, hasta dónde recuerdo, en general son atómicos con la sentencia de update/insert/delete, o sea, si funcionó el insert, funcionó el trigger asociado. Si el trigger no llega a funcionar, se "rollbaquea" automaticamente la sentencia de insert. Pero habría confirmarlo en los manuales de PostgreSql

Comment: @PatricioMoracho _rollbaquea_ depordiós santísimo. Ya lo vi todo ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Patricio Moracho, buscaré haber si encuentro la información.

Comment: @Alfabravo, por eso las comillas ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero revisemos las

### Características de las transacciones de bases de datos

En las bases de datos relacionales, como PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, etc. **toda operación** se lleva a cabo en el contexto de una **transacción**.

Las transacciones le dan el característico sabor ácido a las bases de datos, donde ácido viene del inglés [`ACID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (en español [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)), que es un acrónimo para las características de las mismas:

- **A**tómicidad: Todo o nada
- **C**onsistencia: La DB parte de un estado consistente y termina en un estado consistente
- **I** -> Aislamiento (Isolation en inglés): Cada transacción ocurre de manera independiente de otras transacciones concurrentes
- **D**urabilidad: Una vez se termina, los datos son durables.

### Respondiendo tu pregunta

Siempre que la base de datos ofrezca cumplir con el principio *ACID*, dado que **toda operación** ocurre en el contexto de una transacción y gracias al principio de **atomicidad** de la misma, **si algo falla antes de terminar la operación, tienes garantía que ninguna operación quedará registrada en la base de datos**.

Pongo la condicionante, puesto que incluyes a *mySQL* en las etiquetas de tu pregunta y, sin ser un experto en ese motor, tengo la sensación que tiene algunos *motores de almacenamiento* que no lo cumplen, por ejemplo *MyISAM* y probablemente otros.

### Pero, no todo ocurre en una transacción, ¿o si?

Este es un comentario que suelo escuchar, y se debe al hecho que hay lenguajes de programación, herramientas y motores de bases de datos que te permiten un manejo **implícito de transacciones**. Es decir, que no siempre tienes que lanzar las sentencias:

- `begin transaction`
- `commit transaction`
- `rollback transaction`

Esto no significa que las transacciones no existan, sino que la capa de conexión, la herramienta o el motor en si están constantemente lanzandolas por ti, por ejemplo, cuando envías una sentencia `insert`, `update`, `delete`, hacen un `begin transaction` automático, y al terminar la ejecución, hacen un `commit transaction` automático.

Pero la transacción como tal y, sobre todo, la garantía de atomicidad, existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias jachguate por responderme y por tomarte el trabajo en las definiciones, continuaré leyendo sobre lo que me compartiste.

Comment: Puede que fallen algunos datos dependiendo [el tipo de transacción que tengas configurado para la operación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html) por defecto es read commited